# Using the basics: Array Descending Order?

Tags: java, arrays

Were now on arrays and the job is to do a list of numbers and then it would show the descending order of those numbers.

Here's the condition: A Nested Loop and a Decisive Structure.

I wasn't able to use this code:

```js
for (iLoop = iNumber.length - 1; iLoop >= 0; iLoop--){
            System.out.println("" + iNumber[iLoop]);
```

Because it wouldn't show a nested loop one nor any decisive structures.

I can't use any sort of method YET. Only the first for loop will do the loop for the array. Here's my code next:

```js
        int iX, iY, iLoop;
        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[]iNumber = new int [10];
        for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < iNumber.length; iIndex++){
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            iNumber [iIndex] = var.nextInt();
        }
        for (iX = 0; iX < iNumber.length; iX++){
            for (iY = iX + 1; iY < iNumber.length; iY++){
                if (iNumber[iX] < iNumber[iY]){
                    iLoop = iNumber[iX];
                    iNumber[iX] = iNumber[iY];
                    iNumber[iY] = iLoop;
                }
            }
        System.out.println("" + iNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can't now think why the output is:

```js
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
[I@1909752
```

I don't know what to do again. Someone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: You are sorting your numbers correctly (although inefficiently) but you are not printing them correctly. Look up "how to print an array in Java" and move `printf` out of the loop.

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate. It is not clear but OP need to print his array without add a loop or a method. Since this code is sorting is the opposite of a bubble sort (from the start to the end), this can be printed after each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the iNumber[] array out of the loop :

```
for(int a : iNumber){
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString(iNumber)` is nice too ;)

Comment: @AxelH yes, another way of printing array.

Comment: can you explain why did the `for` loop had a `:` inside it?

Comment: This character will list all the elements of the for loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Comment: Thank you guys so much... all of you were helpful!

Comment: @KenProgrammer **Only the first for loop will do the loop for the array**. Your requirements is done to make you undestand the sort algorithm. You don't need/shouldn not use a other loop for that. **This is exactly the same thing as your loop posted in the question by the way...** The one you said "_I wasn't able to use this code:_"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sorting your array by setting the smallest value first into `iNumber[iX]` by iterating the elements after that point `iY = iX + 1`. You can simply print the `iNumber[iX]`, each inner loop will set the correct value in that position

```
for (iX = 0; iX < iNumber.length; iX++){
    for (iY = iX + 1; iY < iNumber.length; iY++){
        if (iNumber[iX] < iNumber[iY]){
            iLoop = iNumber[iX];
            iNumber[iX] = iNumber[iY];
            iNumber[iY] = iLoop;
        }
     }
    System.out.println("" + iNumber[iX]); //Print the actual value
}
```

This will nicely print every value of `iNumber[iX]` after the loop setting his value.